# Setting new state won't re-render the component with React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to make a workout tracker, and I'm using hooks and useState. I have a component called item-exercise, in which there's a 2 field "form" to add a new set with weights and reps. When user clicks the Add button, it adds the set in the Firebase database, then it sets the state to all empty strings.

Here's the function :

```
const [newSet, setNewSet] = useState({
    weight: '',
    reps: '',
    count: 1
});

const handleAddNewSet = () => {
    const setNotation = `${newSet.count}=${newSet.weight}+${newSet.reps}`;

    addNewSet(id, workoutId, name, setNotation);

    setNewSet({
        ...newSet,
        weight: '',
        reps: '',
        count: newSet.count + 1
    })
}

<div className="item-set">
    <ClassicButton onClick={handleAddNewSet}>Add</ClassicButton>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Weight" name="weight" onChange={(event) => handleChangeNewSet(event)} value={newSet.weight} />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Reps" name="reps" onChange={(event) => handleChangeNewSet(event)} value={newSet.reps} />
</div>
```

The AddNewSet() function works fine, it adds sets as it should. The issue is that it doesn't re-render the component after adding the set and setting the state, refreshing the page makes the sets appear, but I want it to re-render the component, since it shouldn't consume too much data and be mobile friendly. The function that sets the state when the inputs change makes it re-render just fine ( I tried a console.log() and it logs after each key input ). So I don't know what makes a useState render the component again, any tips ?

Thanks !

Comment: can you post the entire code example?

Comment: What does the addNewSet function do?

Comment: @EthanLipkind Yes here it is https://jsfiddle.net/jtxek74v/

Comment: @MosheSommers I added a jsfiddle link with the function. Basically it just sets a new value in an array in Firestore, doesn't return anything

Comment: The code required to reproduce the problem should be in the question, not off-site. I'm also not 100% sure I understand the problem. Are you saying the newly added set should be rendered somewhere? It looks to me like you are reseting the state. Please provide more context and clarity.

Comment: I really thought I was clear enough, sorry about that. Basically I want the ItemExercise component to re-render when a set is added ( to save data by not reloading the full page, and to be more dynamic ). Also I didn't add the code to reproduce the problem in the OP because I think I should have added more characters around the code, there's a limit in the ratio between Code/Full Text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try Adding newSet as a dependency parameter in useEffect

```
  useEffect(() => {
        fetchSets(id, workoutId, name);
    }, [newSet])
```

Comment: Woaw that is it, thank you ! Could you explain why's that ?

Comment: fetchSets will work only the first time the application loads.We need to trigger the rerender each time when handleAddNewSet function is called so to do that we are keeping newSet as dependency parameter to useEffect so that fetchSets would be called everytime when newSet value is changed.